# What does graduated mean in the Netherlands?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduation, netherlands

I have been admitted to a Master in the Netherlands, but my diploma will be awarded after the enroloment date there. However, the university says they can process my admission if I send them an official letter stating that *"I have graduated", completed my course work, and that the diploma will be awarded later.*

In my country and university, the list of students that will receive the diploma is authorized by the Academic Council first and diplomas awarded later. When the list is issued, the Council gives a letter stating that you are graduating. I am not sure if such letter is the equivalent to what the Dutch University needs. Anyone at a Dutch university knows what they exactly want?

Edit: Official documments at my University are issued in Spanish, not in English, therefore I have to get the document translated by an official translator. Hereby, I want to the document to be sharp enough to avoid changes in sense or missinterpretations in any stage.

Comment: Is there any chance you won't get the degree? I think they just want to make sure you will fulfil the requirements.

Comment: Another way to describe this (which is very difficult to misinterpret) is that you are *eligible to graduate*.

Comment: @Davidmh After the list issued by the Council, its official: You ARE graduating, and there is no turning back.

Comment: @Moriarty  That might be a good term to use. The official letter won't be issued in English, instead I will have it in Spanish and then officially translated. That is the reason why I want to have the most precise terms and to avoid miss interpretations.

Answer (score 4):

I'm Dutch and did my bachelor/master and PhD studies at a Dutch university (Utrecht), but can't claim to know exactly what they want; for that you'd really need to get in contact with the people at the university who are in charge of the admission procedure.

That said, I think they want an official confirmation that you passed all requirements necessary to get your degree, and so it seems that the council letter might be sufficient.

Comment: Agree, they mean whether you have passed the requirements ('geslaagd' in Dutch).

Answer (score 2):

I also got my graduate degree in Spain and sent the transcript in Spanish to the Irish university where I did my PhD. They took care of everything else. Administrators understand there are different systems and will usually do their best to accommodate you, but because of the different systems they might not have a standard procedure.

What I suggest is that as soon as your transcript is ready you send a copy to the Dutch university asking if that is enough (they might even have someone who speaks Spanish in their office) and at the same time send it for official translation to English in case you need backup.

As for the diploma, I would not worry too much, I collected my graduate diploma itself (i.e. the piece of paper) after my doctoral one.